# How to set up a domain from namelist in WRF?

Tags: models, numerical-modelling, wrf

I'm fairly inexperienced with WRF and was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of any helpful resources for it.

The task I have is to make a simple 9 km domain, but I'm having trouble understanding what some of the variables actually do/mean?

Specifically,  e_we/sn , dx/dy , and how a nested domain works.

Comment: WRF domain configuration is overall well documented (http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/docs/user_guide/users_guide_chap3.html). What variables do you struggle with, specifically? It would be helpful if you edit your question with more information.

Comment: You should have a look at the annotated `namelist` in [namelist.README]( https://pubs.usgs.gov/sir/2014/5089/downloads/namelist.README). With nested domains you specify a comma separated string of parameters for each value.

Answer (score 2):

There is a WRF domain Wizard offered by ESRL. You can download it [here](http://esrl.noaa.gov/gsd/wrfportal/DomainWizard.html). Also, don't make the same mistake I made using Lambert Conformal- keep stand_lon the same as your ref_lon.